# Identifying Consecutive Months

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I've been using an answer that you posted back in 2010 to understand how to use a CTE in order to identify orders with consecutive months in SQL.  I've finally got my head wrapped around the bulk of this query but don't understand the very last few lines and why you choose the dates you did.

[TSQL Finding Order that occurred in 3 consecutive months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743508/tsql-finding-order-that-occurred-in-3-consecutive-months/3755124#3755124)

> WHERE
>     EXISTS (
>        SELECT 1
>        FROM
>           Anchors A
>        WHERE
>           O.CustID = A.CustID
>           AND O.OrderDate >= DateAdd(Month, A.Ind, '19991201')
>           AND O.OrderDate < DateAdd(Month, A.Ind, '20000301')

Why did you choose the dates of 19991201 and 20000301?

Thanks so much.  I hope you get a chance to respond.  Understanding this would open up a whole new layer of understanding for me.

Michael

Comment: That information is explained in the text that accompanies the code. (Look at the sample data in the question itself first.) Posting an entire new question addressed to a single user isn't really how things work here; once you've earned the comment privilege (at 50 reputation), you can leave comments below the answer asking for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

19991201 and 20000301 are dates in format YYYYMMDD and your where clause use MONTH.

So, if you needs 3 consecutive months you will get Dec/99, Jan/2000 and Feb/2000 with the where clause that you wrote.